# Screen size not updating when entering fullscreen

Tags: python, pygame

When entering fullscreen, the window enters fullscreen, but colours do not. I've tried checking if it is in fullscreen and refreshing with the RESIZE property, but this only works for when being resized outside of fullscreen. Code:

```
import time
import ctypes, pygame
from Game import Character
from pygame.locals import (
    K_UP,
    K_DOWN,
    K_LEFT,
    K_RIGHT,
    K_ESCAPE,
    K_F11,
    KEYDOWN,
    QUIT
)
print("Starting")

global active
global screen

user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
SCREEN_WIDTH = int(round(user32.GetSystemMetrics(0) / 2, 0))
SCREEN_HEIGHT = int(round(user32.GetSystemMetrics(1) / 2, 0))

timeOne = time.time()

pygame.init()

def Main():
    active = True
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), pygame.RESIZABLE)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

    print("Done. Complete in ", round(time.time()-timeOne, 2), "seconds.")

    while active:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                active = False
            elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    active = False
                elif event.key == K_F11:
                    if screen.get_flags() & pygame.FULLSCREEN:
                        pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
                    else:
                        pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
            elif event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE:
                screenSize = event.size
                screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screenSize, pygame.RESIZABLE)

        screen.fill((0, 0, 255))
        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

Main()
```

This is my first time in pygame, so apologies in advance for any rookie mistakes.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by "colours do not [enter fullscreen]" ?

Comment: @Kingsley If the original screen, when not in fullscreen, is 100px x 100px (for simplicity) the screen turns blue, because I told it to fill the screen. However, if I press F11 and enter fullscreen, the window fills the screen, but the blue box is still only 100px x 100px

Answer (score 0):

Code I have working determines the screen dimensions when the display switches windowed ↔ fullscreen.  I don't think the VIDEORESIZE event is fired in the switch, since the video *size* isn't actually changed (maybe there is a way to get this fired, but I think differing fullscreen Vs windowed sizes is a bit of a historical relic).

The upshot of this is that the display has to be re-initialised during the switch.  The program below will switch between windowed ↔ fullscreen mode on <kbd>F11</kbd>, painting the entire screen blue.  There's a few older code-snippets and comments on this switching technique floating around teh internets, with changes to mouse handling etc.  I found that these are no longer necessary ... at least on my test system.  (Please let us know if this needs something further.)

```
import pygame

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH      = 1600
WINDOW_HEIGHT     = 900
WINDOW_FULLSCREEN = False

SKY_BLUE = ( 61,  55, 254)

### Initialisation
pygame.init()
SURFACE = pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE
window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Full Screen Test")


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    # Handle user-input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            window  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), SURFACE )

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_q] and ( keys[pygame.K_RCTRL] or keys[pygame.K_LCTRL] ) ):
        print("^Q")
        done = True
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_F11] ):
        print("fullscreen toggle")
        pygame.display.toggle_fullscreen()
        new_screen  = pygame.display.get_surface()
        bits        = new_screen.get_bitsize()      
        screen_info = pygame.display.Info()
        new_width   = screen_info.current_w
        new_height  = screen_info.current_h 
        print("new_width=%d, new_height=%d" % (new_width, new_height) )
        if ( window.get_flags() & pygame.FULLSCREEN ): 
            flags = pygame.FULLSCREEN | pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF
        else:
            flags = pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.RESIZABLE
        pygame.display.quit()
        pygame.display.init()
        window        = pygame.display.set_mode( ( new_width, new_height ), flags, bits )
        WINDOW_WIDTH  = new_width
        WINDOW_HEIGHT = new_height
        #pygame.key.set_mods( 0 ) #HACK: work-a-round for a SDL bug??

    # Update the window, but not more than 60fps
    window.fill( SKY_BLUE )
    pygame.display.flip()

    # Clamp FPS
    clock.tick_busy_loop(60)

    # Failsafe - exit after 15 seconds (in case your display goes sqrilly)
    if ( pygame.time.get_ticks() > 15000 ):
        print("Exiting Failsafe")
        break

pygame.quit()
```